# 2004 Crown Vic seat belt tensioner won't extend

Tags: ford, belt, seat, crown-victoria

2004 Crown Vic had right rear door replaced, they didn't hang hinges carefully and door wouldn't open easily.  I unbolted the front seat belt pretensioner from the door post to access the lower hinge bolts and when I put everything back together the seat belt won't extend.  Unbolting the pretensioner again allows it to retract even further but it won't extend.

Is there a quick fix or do I have to buy another pretensioner?  And what to I do to keep from causing the same problem on the replacement?

Comment: if it retracts all the way, what happens?  You can't ever extend it?

Comment: It's now retracted to where it's maybe 16 inches above where it's supposed to be, up against a thick wire thing that holds the belt against your shoulder.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's not quite at the correct angle, so as you try to pull out the belt, you're not pulling it square, which is causing the pretensioner to latch and stop you pulling it at all - IIRC it doesn't need to be far off square for this to happen.

Comment: I pried off one of the plastic covers just to release whatever was holding it so we could avoid getting a ticket for not wearing seat belt, and there was a ball bearing in a little cage thing, I don't remember it but I must have unbolted it and tilted it before unplugging it and it triggered somehow, although it doesn't look "blown".  I guess I'll just have to buy another one so it'll actually work if we have an accident.